# Not able to send card number using sendkeys in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using XPath to locate the text box and trying to send card numbers but am not able to do so.

I'm getting an error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`

I've mentioned the code I'm using for that and also attached the snapshot of the page for reference.

[image: page]

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"encryptedCardNumber\"]")).sendKeys("...");
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML source?

Comment: Are you sure the xpath is right? And we can't help you, because we don't know the DOM.

Comment: <input id="encryptedCardNumber" type="text" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="24" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" aria-label="Card number field" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ariaErrorField" class="js-iframe-input input-field" data-type="gsf" style="display: block;"> @YaDav MaNish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the give HTML source, you could use the XPath as

```
//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber' and @aria-label='Card number field']
```

You could use `explicitWait` as I see you use `implicitWait` before the Card Number field

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber' and @aria-label='Card number field']"))).sendKeys("....");
```

Also, I think you can check for the `Iframe` on the page it might be the reason for the above Exception

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("Iframe")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Payment details is inside an iframe. You need to switch to the iframe as

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='targetFrame']")));
```